# Is this Big-O Notation Correct for this Simple Sort Function (Python)?

Tags: python, function, big-o

Suppose we have the following function:

```
def sort_list(list_of_strings):
    """Take a list of strings, sort the letters in each string,
    and then sort the full list. The list is modified in place."""
    for i in range(len(list_of_strings)):
        list_of_strings[i] = ''.join(sorted(list_of_strings[i]))
    list_of_strings.sort()
```

Would it be correct to say that this has big-O notation of `O(n)` because the length of time it takes for the function to run depends on the length of `list_of_strings`?

Comment: This says that yes, the length of time increases linearly with the size of the list, so it is O(n)? [What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation)

Comment: The complexity of this is determined by both the length of `list_of_strings` and the lengths of the items in `list_of_strings` since you are sorting those. In general you can't sort arbitrary things faster than `O(nlogn)` so I think it is misleading to call this function `O(n)`.

Comment: Since you are actually working on each element of your list, your input size is not simply the number of elements in `list_of_strings`, but the combined *length* of those elements.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting a list of size N takes O(N * log(N)) time (generally, it depends on the exact input and the algorithm used, but Python's builtin sorting functions don't do worse than that).

Doing something in a loop multiplies the runtime, and doing things sequentially means adding the runtime together.

This means, given `N = len(list_of_strings)` and `M = max(len(string) for string in list_of_strings)`, the runtime for the loop is `N * O(M * log(M)) = O(N * M * log(M))`, and the bit afterwards is `O(N * log(N))`, which means the runtime for `sort_list` is `O(N * M * log(M) + N * log(N))`.